# Calculate formula downwards with openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, formula, openpyxl

I have a a spreadsheet with column A containing dates. I am using a formula to see the difference in days between A1 and A2, A1 and A3 etc, using this excel formula in column B.

```
=datedif(A1,$A1$1,"D")
```

When dragging down manually in excel it changes to

```
=datedif(A2,$A$1,"D")
```

However my script populates the original formula down all of Column B, keeping A1 instead of moving down to A2, A3 and so on. Here is my script.

```py
for row in ws8.iter_rows(min_col=2, max_col=2, min_row=1):
    for cell in row:
        cell.value = '=datedif(A1,$A$1,"D")'
```

Answer (score 0):

Be careful to include a `max_row` value, if you know it.

```py
ws8 = wb.active
for i,row in enumerate(ws8.iter_rows(min_col=2, max_col=2, max_row=10)):
    for cell in row:
        cell.value = f'=datedif(A{i+1},$A$1,"D")'
```

For older versions of python, without f-strings:

```py
ws8 = wb.active
for i,row in enumerate(ws8.iter_rows(min_col=2, max_col=2, max_row=10)):
    for cell in row:
        cell.value = '=datedif(A{},$A$1,"D")'.format(i+1)
```

**Output**:

[image: Output]

Comment: I am getting invalid syntax at the closing ' of the formula

Comment: It worked for me, can you double check that you've copied over exactly what I provided?

Comment: Never use a counter when `enumerate()` will do. Even better, use `cell.row`

Comment: @CharlieClark Good point, thanks. I will look further into cell.row.

Answer (score 0):

You are pasting it as a string which is then later translated to a formula. 
i dont know python contatenation works, but you need to pass the row number in there:

```
howcell.value = '=datedif(A'+ row ',$A$1,"D")'
```